# Javascript seting dom event to prototype method in constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm having some Javascript woes, lets say we have a constructor

```
function test(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.element.onfocus = function() { this.onfocus(); }
}

test.prototype.onfocus = function() {
  alert("focused");
}

new test(document.getElementByID("E1"));
```

So I am trying to dynamically set the focus event inside the constructor, but it doesn't seem to work, and I can't figure it out.

Anyone help?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, and in the context of `this.element.onfocus = function() {this.onfocus(); }`, second **this** is the element who fired the event.

In other words, your code should be like this if you want to work in a proper way:

```
function test(element) {
  this.element = element;

  var currentObject = this;
  this.element.onfocus = function() {currentObject.onfocus(); }
}
```

Don't think JavaScript is a decent object-oriented programming language, as it's prototype-oriented and it has some weak things like one that's affecting your code.

Why don't you read this article? I belive it'll clarify **this** keyword for you:

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-why-the-this-keyword-breaks

Comment: Thanks very much, this works great, I will take your advice and read the article as well.

Comment: It's not about doing spam, but maybe you're interested in some OOP implementation I did for JavaScript and it works like a charm, as I'm using in some personal projects I'm going to release to the open source community: http://joopl.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You must store a reference to 'this', because the onfocus function is in another context and the 'this' refers to something else:

```
function test(element) {
  this.element = element;
  var that = this;
  this.element.onfocus = function() { that.onfocus(); }
}
```